# The difference among alpha,beta and stable in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, release

Can you explain the different features among alpha, beta and stable in kubernetes?

And I also want to know what the General Availability ( a.k.a GA ).

Thank a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Alpha means the feature is disabled by default and may change wildly before it exits alpha. Beta means on by default, stable for most use, but still might change before GA. GA means the feature will not change in backwards incompatible ways and has the full trust of the project behind it.